# Automatically add LDAP directory to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, address-book, ldap, autoit

Is it possible to add a new LDAP-directory to the outlook addressbook with a script?

I haven't found an appropriate registry key. I would prefer a .reg file. A .msp file created with Office setup programm didn't work reliably.